# php IF is not working in my code

Tags: php, if-statement

When i run this I allways get: (what ever is wdl form).

```
copy ("templates/colors/win.txt", "tips/$today/color.txt");
copy ("templates/text/win.txt", "tips/$today/wdl.txt");
```

which means the last commands, the **if** on my php code is not working.
the code:

```
<?php
echo ("Setting up colors...");
if($_GET["wdl"] == "D");
{
    copy ("templates/colors/dr.txt", "tips/$today/color.txt");
    copy ("templates/text/dr.txt", "tips/$today/wdl.txt");
}
if($_GET["wdl"] == "L");
{
    copy ("templates/colors/lose.txt", "tips/$today/color.txt");
    copy ("templates/text/lose.txt", "tips/$today/wdl.txt");
}
if($_GET["wdl"] == "W");
{
    copy ("templates/colors/win.txt", "tips/$today/color.txt");
    copy ("templates/text/win.txt", "tips/$today/wdl.txt");
}
?>
```

how can i fix it?

the solusion was to remove the: ex: `;` from `if($_GET["wdl"] == "W");`

Comment: check switch case witch run fast and best for execucation
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18594142/php-if-is-not-working-in-my-code/18594313#18594313

Comment: @User2670708 Please be sure to mark one of the answers as accepted and not just paste the answer in your question :-) thanks.

Comment: yes, but i have to wait some minutes to accepted an answer, so please wait. thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is best way to replace if with switch statement

```
<?php
echo ("Setting up colors...");
switch($_GET["wdl"]) {
  case "D" :
       copy ("templates/colors/dr.txt", "tips/$today/color.txt");
       copy ("templates/text/dr.txt", "tips/$today/wdl.txt");
       break;
  case "W" :
     copy ("templates/colors/win.txt", "tips/$today/color.txt");
     copy ("templates/text/win.txt", "tips/$today/wdl.txt");
      break;
  case "L" :
     copy ("templates/colors/lose.txt", "tips/$today/color.txt");
     copy ("templates/text/lose.txt", "tips/$today/wdl.txt");
      break;
 }
?>
```

Comment: this is something different from what I make, and its working!

Answer (score 9):

Remove the `;` at the end of the `if`, before the `{`

```
if($_GET["wdl"] == "D");
{
```

should be

```
if($_GET["wdl"] == "D")
{
```

and so on..

`;` is an instruction separator. [Read more here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php)

This is a common area of mistake, so to avoid this, you could do

```
if($_GET["wdl"] == "D") {
   ...
```

That way you can avoid the accidental `;` after the looping constructs

So the code block looks like this:

```
<?php
    echo ("Setting up colors...");
    if($_GET["wdl"] == "D") {
        copy ("templates/colors/dr.txt", "tips/$today/color.txt");
        copy ("templates/text/dr.txt", "tips/$today/wdl.txt");
    }
    if($_GET["wdl"] == "L") {
        copy ("templates/colors/lose.txt", "tips/$today/color.txt");
        copy ("templates/text/lose.txt", "tips/$today/wdl.txt");
    }
    if($_GET["wdl"] == "W") {
        copy ("templates/colors/win.txt", "tips/$today/color.txt");
        copy ("templates/text/win.txt", "tips/$today/wdl.txt");
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
if($_GET["wdl"] == "W");
```

Because of semicolon(`;`) after `IF` statement

Remove semicolon after all `IF` statement. It looks like

```
if($_GET["wdl"] == "D") {
    copy ("templates/colors/dr.txt", "tips/$today/color.txt");
    copy ("templates/text/dr.txt", "tips/$today/wdl.txt");
}
if($_GET["wdl"] == "L") {
    copy ("templates/colors/lose.txt", "tips/$today/color.txt");
    copy ("templates/text/lose.txt", "tips/$today/wdl.txt");
}
if($_GET["wdl"] == "W") {
    copy ("templates/colors/win.txt", "tips/$today/color.txt");
    copy ("templates/text/win.txt", "tips/$today/wdl.txt");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if($_GET["wdl"] == "D"){
    copy ("templates/colors/dr.txt", "tips/$today/color.txt");
    copy ("templates/text/dr.txt", "tips/$today/wdl.txt");
}else if($_GET["wdl"] == "L"){
    copy ("templates/colors/lose.txt", "tips/$today/color.txt");
    copy ("templates/text/lose.txt", "tips/$today/wdl.txt");
}else if($_GET["wdl"] == "W"){
    copy ("templates/colors/win.txt", "tips/$today/color.txt");
    copy ("templates/text/win.txt", "tips/$today/wdl.txt");
}
```

You need to remove the `;` from the end of the `if` statements and you can also make it an `else if` to prevent it from testing the remaining statements once one matches.